# Derivative of ${\lVert{ABC-D}\rVert}_F^2$ with respect to $B$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

What is the derivative of ${\lVert{ABC-D}\rVert}_F^2$ with respect to $B$?

where:

${\lVert{.}\rVert}_F^2$ represents the power 2 of the frobenius norm

$A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix

$B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix

$C$ is an $m \times l$ matrix

$D$ is an $n \times l$ matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) for reference.

Let $E=ABC$.
First,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial E} \|E-D\|_F^2 = 2 (E-D) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}.$$

Next, if $a_i^\top$ denotes the $i$th row of $A$, and $c_j$ denotes the $j$th column of $C$, then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial B} (ABC)_{ij}= \frac{\partial}{\partial B} a_i^\top B c_j = a_ic_j^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}.$$
So $\frac{\partial}{\partial B}(ABC)$ can be viewed as a big $n \times l$ matrix where the $(i,j)$ entry is itself the $m \times m$ matrix $a_i c_j^\top$.

Applying chain rule gives
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial B} \|ABC-D\|_F^2 = 2(ABC-D) \circ \frac{\partial}{B} (ABC) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^l (ABC-D)_{ij} a_i c_j^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m},$$
where "$\circ$" denotes some sort of [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (just refer to the double sum).

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, the final answer can be written as
$$2A^\top (ABC-D) C^\top.$$

Comment: Thanks :)
Is there a matrix form for your answer?
for example:
$A^T(ABC-D)C^T$

Answer (score 0):

Define the residual matrix
$$R=ABC-D$$
and denote the trace/Frobenius product with a colon
$$A:B = \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^TB\right)$$
Write the function in terms of the new variable.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= R:R \\
d\phi &= 2R:dR = 2R:A\,dB\,C = 2A^TRC^T:dB \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B} &= 2A^TRC^T = 2A^T(ABC-D)C^T \\
}$$